# Where to store data files generated by linux software?

Tags: python, linux, datastore, project-structure

I have a Python script with a `make install` (by default to /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/) option available. But the script also generates files with user-specific mutable data during script's normal usage. It seems to me that I should not keep compiled script files in couple with data. What is conventional default place to store software data in such cases?

Comment: Data that's generated at runtime during the normal use of the software, or data that's installed at `make install` time?

Comment: during normal use of the software

Comment: I think 'it depends'.  Does the user need to have control of the data? Many programs use users' home directories.  Data that belongs to users that is unobtrusive can go in a dotted subdirectory of the user's home directory.  Data storage at the system level, like data saved in files by mySQL database server, is often in a subdirectory of /var/lib

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Summarizing from the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html):

Immutable architecture-independent data should go in `/usr/share` or `/usr/local/share`. Mutable data should go in the user's home directory if it's user-specific ([XDG](http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html) provides more guidance here), or in `/var` if it's system-wide (this usually requires a group-owned directory and files, and a setgid application, to allow writing to a shared file).

`/usr/share` and `/usr/local/share` usually have a structure that somewhat mirrors `/usr/lib` and `/usr/local/lib`; I don't know about Python, but Perl has a module [File::ShareDir](http://p3rl.org/File::ShareDir) that helps a module with installing and accessing data in a share directory corresponding to the directory where the module is installed.

And don't forget the other option: just *ask the user* where the data should go.

Comment: At what stage would you recommend to ask the user? At 'make install' or at launch? Should I make asking optional? It is user-specific mutable data case.